# iOS UIWebView goback or goforward always reload webView automatically, How can I stop the webview reload?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

iOS UIWebView goback or goforward always reload webView automatically, How can I stop the webview reload? Because some urls like "https://www.sina.cn/", If the webview request the url ,You'll notice that the webview can't goforward. And how do I deal with this situation?

You can see my code at https://github.com/misscxuan/WebBackTest

Comment: Show us your work.

Answer (score 0):

if the webview request the url as "https://www.sina.cn/", and request another url, then webview goback, you'll find webview can't goforward.

Answer (score 0):

You could stop the load task in the `UIWebviewDelegate` Method `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? How do I know the normal load and the back or forward load?

Comment: Try like this in the Method.```if [(request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"some urls"] && navigationType == someType) {return NO/YES}

Comment: If I return no here, the page will not be loaded, so there will be a blank.

Comment: where do you load your webview,viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad?

Comment: I load my webview in viewDidLoad.

Comment: define like this:```{
    BOOL _isLoad;
}```.
viewDidLoad:```_isLoad = NO;```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```if (!_isLoad) {
        _isLoad = YES;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;```

Comment: This is my code. Can you help me modify it.https://github.com/misscxuan/WebBackTest